# How to resolve "snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request"?

Tags: ubuntu, package

I have encountered “snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request” error while installing applications from Synaptic Package Manager in Ubuntu.I tried to use Software Center also but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used snap to resolve this issue and it worked.
I have installed skype to check this.

`snap find "skype"`

Then used the command in the following fashion to install the snap package:

`sudo snap install skype --classic`

::Snap is universal packaging system launched by Ubuntu.It allows you to use these Snap packaged applications on any Snap supported Linux distributions, not just Ubuntu.::

Comment: Have you been able to start skype? (after installing it)

Comment: running "sudo snap install skype --classic " was successful, but couldn't start Skype.

Comment: In what way did you try to access skype after installation?

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04: `error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "skype" (33) ([daemon-reload] failed with exit status 1: Failed to execute operation: Connection reset by peer
)
`   When I try to re-run it, I get: `error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/skype: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
`

Answer (score 1):

The better way for the installation of your application will be using **snap**. Whatever application you are installing through synaptic, try it with snap.

Just take the keyword of the application name. As an example, I take **visual studio code**.

snap is providing the installation of visual studio code. Use these steps in command line.

> ***Step 1:*** snap find "visual studio code"
>
> ***Step 2:*** sudo snap install vscode --classic

***Please note that the name "vscode" came from the result of Step 1.***

After the execution, the window opens automatically and then you can continue.

I tried installing skype with this, and got it done successfully.

For more details of snap, and its errors, use the link https://youtu.be/tmqBlc7FFgg

Answer (score 0):

For Any type of application type the command described above. As i got the same issue while downloading visual studio.

```
snap find "visual studio code"
```

Follow this link to get better idea.[enter link description here](https://itsfoss.com/snapd-error-ubuntu/)